# Create a case control pair for time stratified case-crossover design

Tags: r

I plan to design a study using a time stratified case crossover approach, in which each
case serves as his own control. Control days have to be on the same
weekday of the same month.  If a person is admitted to hospital on Friday in
a certain Month, then all other Fridays in that month will be control days. Depending on the date of admission and month, there will be 3 or 4 controls.

For instance, if a person is admitted to hospital today (27.12.2013), all
Fridays in December (6th, 13th and 20th) will be controls, thus providing 3 controls.
On the other hand, if another patient is admitted on the New Year, Wednesday 1, 1, 2014, all other Wednesdays of January 2014 (8,15,22 and 29)  will be control days.

The dput below shows the event days which I currently have( event_date) and the intended control days(referent date).
How could I setup such scheme? T

```
structure(list(event_date = structure(c(12539, 12539, 12539, 
12539, 12544, 12544, 12544, 12545, 12545, 12545, 12550, 12550, 
12550, 12563, 12563, 12563, 12567, 12567, 12567, 12567, 14065, 
14065, 14065), class = "Date"), referent_date = structure(c(12546, 
12560, 12567, 12553, 12558, 12565, 12551, 12566, 12552, 12559, 
12543, 12557, 12564, 12556, 12542, 12549, 12553, 12539, 12546, 
12560, 14086, 14072, 14079), class = "Date")), .Names = c("event_date", 
"referent_date"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
"15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23"))
```

Comment: From what I can see, you repeat the first block twice more and add a `strata` column? Does this depend on the `death` variable?

Comment: Yes, the death variable gives clue to the number of strata to be created.  The three events of April 1 represent strata 1 to 3 and the single event on April 2 will be strata number 4 etc while April 3 will have the next 4 strata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about filtering candidate dates using wday() and month() from lubridate?

```
require(lubridate)

compDates <- function(event_date) {
  # to be comparable, reference dates must have the same month and wday as event
  # but can't be exactly the same date
    possible_refs <- as.Date((event_date - 30) : (event_date + 30), 
                             origin="1970-01-01") 
    possible_refs[month(possible_refs)==month(event_date)
                        & wday(possible_refs)==wday(event_date)
                        & event_date != possible_refs]
}

some_event_dates <- structure(c(12539, 12544, 12545, 12550, 
                                12563, 12567,14065), class = "Date")

some_event_dates

lapply(some_event_dates, compDates)
```

should provide the desired list.